# Calculated Grid Width changes after Browser Zoom

Tags: html, google-chrome, zooming

i've built my own grid system which worked just fine... until now.
As you can see in my screenshots below, chrome changes my fixed border and content sizes to some weird floating values.

Does anybody know why this happens or can explain to me how I could prevent it?

Before Zoom:

[image: Before Zoom]

After Zoom:

[image: After Zoom]

Cheers!

Comment: Please describe how your grid works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give a specific answer since your question does not involve detailed information about your self-built grid system. Nevertheless it sounds like a problem with sub-pixel rendering (see https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/LayoutUnit) as I have also had several problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like box-sizing: border-box calculates some funny values when zooming. I had to change box-sizing to content-box for my wrapping container. That did the trick!